# Fazer aparecer botão apenas de uma <li> específica

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, react, express.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web onde esse botão verde de confirmar mostrado na imagem, só é exibido quando o botão azul de editar é clicado. Esses "cards" são li's que são gerados dinamicamente conforme eu realizo um novo cadastro. O que acontece é que, quando eu clico no botão de editar (o lapis azul) de qualquer card, ele exibe o botão confirmar de todos os cards. Eu queria saber como faz pra ele exibir o botao confirmar apenas para o card que foi clicado.

[image]

[image]

**Imagem 1:** Exemplo de cards em que deixou os botões de confirmar visível.

**Imagem 2:** os li's são gerados através de um map que percorre um vetor, recebendo todos os cadastros de "reparos" (tabela do banco).

---

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
const [nameClass, setNameClass] = useState({ className: "hideButton" });
```

Eu tenho esses dois estados que eu guardo a visibilidade do select e o nome da classe do botão confirmar

```
function showButton() {
        setVisible(!visible);
        setNameClass({ className: "confirmButton" });
        if (nameClass.className === "confirmButton") {
            setNameClass({ className: "hideButton" });
        }
    };
```

O showButton() altera a disabled do select pra falso e altera o nome da classe do botão confirmar.

Quando o className ta setado como hideButton, o botão confirmar recebe esse estilo:

```
.dashboard-container main.reparos li .hideButton {
    display: none;
}
```

Quando o ShowButton() altera pra confirmButton, o botão confirmar recebe esse:

```
.dashboard-container main.reparos li .confirmButton {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: filter 0.2s;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    animation: surge 400ms;
}

.dashboard-container main.reparos li .confirmButton:hover {
    filter: brightness(92%);
}
```

Comment: O que faz essa função `showButton()`? Podes colocar o código (em texto!) aqui?

Comment: Substitua a imagem por código, também.

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigo pensei de uma forma mais genérica mas creio que irá te ajudar, no caso usei o index do array que é facilmente acessado em algums metodos que percorrem arrays no JS, no caso usei o **.map**. Mas você tem pode usar com base no id ou qualquer **valor único**, também não me mative apegado ao seu estilo, somente respondi sua primeira pergunta: "Eu queria saber como faz pra ele exibir o botao confirmar apenas para o card que foi clicado".

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [cardsState, setCardsState] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Primeiro Card",
      text: "bla bla bla",
      updated: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Segundo Card",
      text: "bla bla bla",
      updated: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "terceiro Card",
      text: "bla bla bla",
      updated: false
    }
  ]);

  const updateCardCallback = useCallback(
    index => {
      return setCardsState(cardsState.map(
        (card, i) => {
          if(i === index){
            return (
              {
                ...card,
                update: true
              }
            )
          }
          return card
        }
      ));
    },
    [cardsState]
  );

  const checkUpdate = update => {
    if (update) {
      return <span>update</span>;
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cardsState.map((card, index) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ border: "2px solid black"}} key={card.id}>
            <h3>{card.title}</h3>
            <button onClick={() => updateCardCallback(index)}>editar</button>
            {checkUpdate(card.updated)}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```